# Converting from Ordinal Time to Date-Time in Python

Tags: python, time

I want to convert a precise ordinal time array (see below) to date-time format (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.sss) in anaconda/python 3. I cannot find any solutions to this problem that considers the precision of the original data.

The ordinal time array looks like:

```
[[733414.07083333]
 [733414.07430556]
 [733414.07777778]
 ...
 [737654.10902778]
 [737654.1125    ]
 [737654.11597222]]
```

`datetime.fromordinal` only works for integer numbers and the decimals MUST be considered in order to obtain the time component to the decimal second.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a tip from a friend, who directed me to another website (https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/100062/datetime.datetime.fromordinal), I have found a solution to this challenge. This is the modified script that I used to convert ordinal time to date-time:

```
import numpy as _np
import datetime
from datetime import date

def _from_ordinal(x, tz=None) :
    ix = int(x)
    dt = date.fromordinal(ix)
    remainder = float(x) - ix
    hour, remainder = divmod(24 * remainder, 1)
    minute, remainder = divmod(60 * remainder, 1)
    second, remainder = divmod(60 * remainder, 1)
    microsecond = int(1e6 * remainder)
    # compensate for rounding errors
    if microsecond < 10 :
        microsecond = 0                             
    elif microsecond > 999990 : 
        microsecond = _np.subtract(1000000,microsecond)
    dt = datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, int(hour), int(minute), int(second), microsecond)
    dt = dt.isoformat(timespec='microseconds')
    if tz is not None:
        dt = dt.astimezone(tz)
    return dt

arrayDateTime = []
for i in range(0,len(arrayOrdinalTime)) :
    dateTime = _from_ordinal(arrayOrdinalTime[i])
    dateTime = dateTime.replace('T', ' ')
    arrayDateTime = _np.append(arrayDateTime, dateTime)
```

Please note, because of the for-loop in this script, processing can take a long time if teh data set is large. I tried to make this work directly with an array, but it failed.

Any tips to make this work directly with an array, therefore to save time, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue and found a faster way to convert from ordinal to datetime, which is done in your first function.

```
import datetime
def OrdinalToDatetime(ordinal):
    plaindate = datetime.date.fromordinal(int(ordinal))
    date_time = datetime.datetime.combine(plaindate, datetime.datetime.min.time())
    return date_time + datetime.timedelta(days=ordinal-int(ordinal))
```

The output would be in case of today `OrdinalToDatetime(737998.46643556)`

```
Out[1]: datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 27, 11, 11, 40, 32386)
```